# How to store ACSII values in an array?

Tags: arrays, c

```
int main() {

    int arr[5], i;

    printf("Enter 5 numbers:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

    }

    printf("ASCII values corresponding to the input numbers:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        printf("%d: %c\n", arr[i], (char)arr[i]);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wLbz.jpg)

I was expecting character where the output is giving blank spaces

Comment: The ascii values 0-31 control characters that are used to communicate with peripherals  and are typically non-printable

Comment: What values are you using as input?

Answer (score 1):

In the current state it would work when giving it 1 number (0-9). Otherwise, you'd have to print multiple values in the second part (e.g. granting it number '45' should result in ASCII 45: {52, 53}.

The reason it's not working as you're expecting is because the scanf method stores decimal value 0-255 when you're using the %d format specifier (1 -> 0x01), whereas using %c specifier results in storing the ASCII value (1 -> 0x31).

Small modification:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[5], i;

    printf("Enter 5 numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("ASCII values corresponding to the input numbers:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        printf("%c: %d\n", (char)arr[i], arr[i]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this expects sequential numbers:

```
Enter 5 numbers:
12345
ASCII values corresponding to the input numbers:
1: 49
2: 50
3: 51
4: 52
5: 53
```

To get it to work for separate inputs, you'd just have to handle (ignore) the control character. If you want to support multiple numbers you'll have to scanf until finding the control character (LF).

Answer (score 0):

There are 256 ASCII characters which can may be divided into three categories:

1. ASCII control characters (0-31 and 127)
2. ASCII printable characters (32-126)
3. Extended ASCII characters

The characters in the first category won't give you visible output so if you tried inputting numbers from within that range, it explains why you didn't get the expected output.

To print the first 5 alphabet characters, use the ASCII values 97 through 101.

Comment: Though notably, some "funky" non-standard ASCII tables back in the days chose to print diverse curious symbols for 0 to 31 as well.

Comment: There are 128 ASCII characters. ASCII is a seven-bit code. “Extended” ASCII characters are not ASCII characters.

Comment: There's nothing known as Extended ASCII (well, there is, but if refers to a completely different thing, meaning the different national symbols associated to 
ASCII characters like spanish Ñ -> \, or currency symbols like pound -> $)  ASCII character set is 7 bits, so only 128 characters in the set.